# Set the UserPrincipalName to be the same as PrimarySMTPAddress?

Tags: powershell

I need to fix the below script where the goal is to set the UserprincipalName to the same as the ProxyAddress SMTP: (PrimarySMTP) entry.

```
$paramGetADUser = @{
    Filter      = "Enabled -eq 'True'"
    Properties  = 'EmailAddress', 'UserPrincipalName', 'SamAccountName'
    SearchBase  = 'OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com'
    SearchScope = 'Subtree'
}

$ADUsers = Get-ADUser @paramGetADUser |
    Where-Object { $_.UserPrincipalName -ne $_.EmailAddress } |
    Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName

foreach ($ADuser in $ADUsers)
{
    Write-Host "Processing $($ADuser.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    $paramSetADUser = @{
        Identity = $ADuser.SamAccountName
        UserPrincipalName = $_.EmailAddress
    }
    
    Set-ADUser @paramSetADUser
    
    Get-ADUser -Identity $ADuser.SamAccountName |
    Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

The script above somehow will reset or set the UserPrincipalName to be empty when there is no EmailAddress value, this is dangerous and NOT what I wanted.

How to prevent the issue above and achieve the standardization of UPN = PrimarySMTPAddress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is correctly talking about getting the primary email address from the users `ProxyAddress` attribute (that is where Exchange also gets it from).
AFAIK, you should not rely on the users `mail` attribute, which may have a totally different value than the one that is actually used for emailing.

I would suggest something like below:

```
# Get-ADUser by default already returns objects with these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
$paramGetADUser = @{
    Filter      = "Enabled -eq 'True'"
    Properties  = 'ProxyAddresses', 'EmailAddress'
    SearchBase  = 'OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com'
    SearchScope = 'Subtree'
}

$result = Get-ADUser @paramGetADUser | ForEach-Object {
    $primaryMail = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -clike 'SMTP:*' }) -replace '^SMTP:'
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($primaryMail)) {
        Write-Warning "User $($_.SamAccountName) does not have a Primary Email Address.."
        continue
    }
    if ($_.UserPrincipalName -eq $primaryMail) {
        Write-Host "User $($_.SamAccountName) already has a correct UPN"
        # output unchanged
        $_ | Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'IsUpdated'; Expression = {'No'}}
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Setting UPN for user $($_.SamAccountName) to '$primaryMail'"
        $_ | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $primaryMail

        # refresh and output
        Get-ADUser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName | 
        Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, @{Name = 'IsUpdated'; Expression = {'Yes'}}
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\somewhere\UserPrincipalNames.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3):

A minor modification to your current code, instead of using `EmailAddress`, use `mail` and use [AD Filter / LDAP Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) to query only for those user that have this attribute set:

```sh
$paramGetADUser = @{
    LDAPFilter  = "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(mail=*))"
    Properties  = 'mail', 'UserPrincipalName', 'SamAccountName'
    SearchBase  = 'OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com'
    SearchScope = 'Subtree'
}

foreach ($ADuser in Get-ADUser @paramGetADUser) {

    if($ADUser.UserPrincipalName -eq $ADuser.mail) {
        continue
    }
    
    Write-Host "Processing $($ADuser.Name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    $paramSetADUser = @{
        Identity = $ADuser.SamAccountName
        UserPrincipalName = $ADuser.mail
    }
    
    Set-ADUser @paramSetADUser
    
    Get-ADUser -Identity $ADuser.SamAccountName |
    Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Comment: @AbrahamZinala morning :) no you're right, but I don't remember if `Set-ADUser -PassThru` would keep the additional attributes (`EmailAddress` in this case)